# ldap server should be reached by the hosting

Tags: php, ldap

when I'm testing ldap_bind it's worked on my test machine because it's on the same domain with my ldap server but when i move the code to web hosting

```
Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /home
```

And i'm access it from browser in the same domain with ldap server,
so ldap server should be reached by the hosting?

```
            <?php
            // using ldap bind
            $ldaprdn  = 'user';     // ldap rdn or dn
            $ldappass = 'pass';  // associated password
            // connect to ldap server
            $ldapconn = ldap_connect("server.com")    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
            if ($ldapconn) {
                // binding to ldap server
                $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
                // verify binding
                if ($ldapbind & strlen($ldappass)>0) {
                   echo "H LDAP bind successful...";
                } else {
                    echo "LDAP bind failed...";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few checkpoints from my side :

- Seems you are using LDAPS i.e. via SSL, so make sure the certificate is there in truststore of host in Web hosting env.
- If you are using hostname instead of IP you may try this:
  $ip = gethostbyname('ldap.example.com');
  $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ip);
- Also check the LDAP port if its not default and you may specify if not default.

Comment: I'm new to ldap can you give me  more details?

Answer (score 0):

The simple BIND operation requires a DN, not just a component of the DN.

Comment: can you give me example I'm new to ldap ?

Comment: Use the full DN in the BIND operation: `ldap_bind($ldapconn,"cn=user,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com",$ldappass);`